# Counting the number of continuous palindromic substrings

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, python-3.x, palindrome

Given a string of lowercase ASCII characters, find all distinct continuous palindromic sub-strings of it.
Here is my code:

```
def palindrome(s):
    if s==s[::-1]:
        return True


noTest=int(input())
s=[]
for _ in range(noTest):
    s.append(input())

count=[]
for word in s:
    letters=[]
    psub=[]
    for l in word:
        letters.append(l)
        if l not in psub:
            psub.append(l)

    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for k in range(i+1,len(letters)+1):
             sub=('').join(letters[i:k])
             #print (i,k,sub)
             if palindrome(sub) and sub not in psub:
                 psub.append(sub)

    count.append(len(psub))

for c in count:
    print (c)
```

**Input:**
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.    Then T test cases follow. Each test case contains a string.

**Output:**
Print the count of distinct continuous palindromic sub-strings of it.

Comment: Could you give a few exemple string with expected result please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Style

Python has a Style Guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is definitly worth reading and trying to apply. You'll find various tools to help you if needed.

The main issues are:

- missing whitespace
- indentation does not always use 4 spaces

Once this is fixed, your code looks like:

```
def palindrome(s):
    if s == s[::-1]:
        return True


noTest = int(input())
s = []
for _ in range(noTest):
    s.append(input())
count = []
for word in s:
    letters = []
    psub = []
    for l in word:
        letters.append(l)
        if l not in psub:
            psub.append(l)

    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(letters) + 1):
            sub = ('').join(letters[i:k])
            # print (i,k,sub)
            if palindrome(sub) and sub not in psub:
                psub.append(sub)
    count.append(len(psub))

for c in count:
    print(c)
```

### Implicit return in `palindrome` and other improvements

In the `palindrome` function, you either return `True` or an implicit None when the end of the function is reached. When your functions does return a value in at least one place, it is much clearer to add an explicit `return None`. However, it'd probably make more sense to return `False` in that case. Trying to add documentation for that function, you would have seen the issue.

Then your function looks like:

```
def palindrome(s):
    """ Return True if string s is a palindrom, False otherwise."""
    if s == s[::-1]:
        return True
    return False
```

However, this can also be written:

```
def palindrome(s):
    """ Return True if string s is a palindrom, False otherwise."""
    return s == s[::-1]
```

### More functions

It would probably worth extracting the code computing the number of palindromic substrings in a function on its own.

It makes the code easier to understand and easier to test (I'll come back to testing later).

Then, your code looks like:

```
def palindrome(s):
    """ Return True if string s is a palindrom, False otherwise."""
    return s == s[::-1]

def number_of_palindrom_substrings(word):
    """ Return the number of palindrom substrings of string s."""
    letters = []
    psub = []
    for l in word:
        letters.append(l)
        if l not in psub:
            psub.append(l)

    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(letters) + 1):
            sub = ('').join(letters[i:k])
            # print (i,k,sub)
            if palindrome(sub) and sub not in psub:
                psub.append(sub)
    return len(psub)


count = []
for word in s:
    count.append(number_of_palindrom_substrings(word))

for c in count:
    print(c)
```

**The `count` list**

Instead of using multiple calls to `append`, you could use a list comprehension to define `count`:

```
count = [number_of_palindrom_substrings(word) for word in s]
```

However, building this list is not even required:

```
for word in s:
    print(number_of_palindrom_substrings(word))
```

**The right data type**

Your store unique palindroms in a list. In order to do so, you check if the string is in the list before adding it. You should use a set to make things easier.

```
def number_of_palindrom_substrings(word):
    """ Return the number of palindrom substrings of string word."""
    letters = []
    psub = set()
    for l in word:
        letters.append(l)
        psub.add(l)

    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(letters) + 1):
            sub = ('').join(letters[i:k])
            if palindrome(sub):
                psub.add(sub)
    return len(psub)
```

**List of letters is not required**

You build a list to contain the successive letters of `word`. This is not required, you can perform whatever operation you like directly on `word`.

```
def number_of_palindrom_substrings(word):
    """ Return the number of palindrom substrings of string s."""
    psub = set()
    for l in word:
        psub.add(l)

    for i in range(len(word)):
        for k in range(i+1, len(word) + 1):
            sub = ('').join(word[i:k])
            if palindrome(sub):
                psub.add(sub)
    return len(psub)
```

Then you can initialise `psub` with a set comprehension:

```
    psub = set(l for l in word)
```

or even better, without a list comprehension:

```
    psub = set(word)
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, you should organize your code by using functions as it will help you simplify it and is better for reusability and testing. As I see it, you can use a function to generate the various substrings of the word, and a function to count the amount of palindromes in a string. You could also organize the remaining top-level code in a `main()` function and guard it with [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do):

```
def palindrome(s):
    if s==s[::-1]:
        return True


def substrings(letters):
    subs = []
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for k in range(i+1,len(letters)+1):
             sub=('').join(letters[i:k])
             subs.append(sub)
    return subs


def count_palindromes(word):
    letters=[]
    psub=[]
    for l in word:
        letters.append(l)
        if l not in psub:
            psub.append(l)

    for sub in substrings(letters):
         if palindrome(sub) and sub not in psub:
             psub.append(sub)

    return len(psub)


def main():
    noTest=int(input())
    s=[]
    for _ in range(noTest):
        s.append(input())

    count=[]
    for word in s:
        count.append(count_palindromes(word))

    for c in count:
        print (c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now we can start tidying things up. For starter, apply [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make it look like other Python code and simplify `main()` as we don't need all those intermediate lists anymore:

```
def main():
    tests_count = int(input())
    for _ in range(tests_count):
        print(count_palindromes(input()))
```

Apply the same kind of improvements to the `palindrome` function:

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]
```

Second, use a better datastructure than lists in `count_palindromes` as checking `l not in psub` or `sub not in psub` is an \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ operation compared to \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ for the same kind of check in a `set`. Besides, `set`s guarantee that each element added in is only added once, so you can get rid of these checks yourself.

```
def count_palindromes(word):
    palindromes = set(word)
    for sub in substrings(word):
        if is_palindrome(sub):
            palindromes.add(sub)
    return len(palindromes)
```

Note that I passed the whole `word` to `substrings` instead of a list of letters, as `len` or slicing (`[i:k]`) would work on both. Also, you could use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) builtin instead of an explicit check which will allow you to write:

```
def count_palindromes(word):
    palindromes = set(word)
    palindromes.update(filter(is_palindrome, substrings(word)))
    return len(palindromes)
```

Lastly, you can optimize substring generation by:

1. getting rid of the `join` call as you already have strings when slicing a string;
2. using a generator rather than building a list and appending to it.

```
def substrings(word):
    word_length = len(word)
    for i in range(word_length):
        for k in range(i + 1, word_length + 1):
            yield word[i:k]
```

Full code:

```
def substrings(word):
    word_length = len(word)
    for i in range(word_length):
        for k in range(i + 1, word_length + 1):
            yield word[i:k]


def is_palindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]


def count_palindromes(word):
    palindromes = set(word)
    palindromes.update(filter(is_palindrome, substrings(word)))
    return len(palindromes)


def main():
    tests_count = int(input())
    for _ in range(tests_count):
        print(count_palindromes(input()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

You could also use the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) module and adapt a bit the `pairwise` recipe to make `substrings` a bit more efficient:

```
import itertools


def substrings(string, size):
    iterators = itertools.tee(string, size)
    substrings_generator = (
            itertools.islice(i, start, None)
            for start, i in enumerate(iterators)
    )
    return map(''.join, zip(*substrings_generator))


def is_palindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]


def count_palindromes(word):
    palindromes = set(word)
    for sub_size in range(2, len(word) + 1):
        palindromes.update(filter(is_palindrome, substrings(word, sub_size)))
    return len(palindromes)


def main():
    tests_count = int(input())
    for _ in range(tests_count):
        print(count_palindromes(input()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```